# How do I call a paintcomponent method?

Tags: java, methods, paintcomponent

Hi I have made an `actionlistener` and I want to call a `paintComponent` method when you click the button?

I have googled it but with no luck.

Here is the `actionlisetener`,

```
graf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    graf();

                }
```

And here is the method,

```
public static void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

    int width = Integer.parseInt(xinwindow.getText());
    int hight = Integer.parseInt(yinwindow.getText());

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine((width/2)- 1, 0, (width/2) +1 , hight);


}
```

How to call it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `paintComponent` method of a `JComponent` object you want to paint.

```
JComponent c = new JComponent() {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = Integer.parseInt(xinwindow.getText());
        int hight = Integer.parseInt(yinwindow.getText());

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine((width/2)- 1, 0, (width/2) +1 , hight);
    }
}
```

And add

```
c.revalidate();
c.repaint();
```

after handling the click in `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Thanks! I gonna try that later :).

Comment: Hi! It didn't work! 
I typed this code
static Component c = new JComponent(){
     static void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         int width = Integer.parseInt(xinwindow.getText());
         int hight = Integer.parseInt(yinwindow.getText());

         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawLine((width/2) - 1, 0, (width/2) +1 , hight);
     }
 }
But it gave me an error at the last line, "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
 FieldDeclaration"

Comment: Look at the answer below to get a better explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with some examples to construct a GUI.

`static` is  for a global, a once occuring instance; one per class. Try to remove all, just the program's entry point:

```
public static void main(String args) {
    JFrame appWindow = new MyFrame();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> appWindow->setVisible(true));
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private MyPanel panel;
    public MyFrame() {
        panel = new MyPanel();
        add(panel);
        panel.addClickListener(evt -> panel.repaint(50L));
     }
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.setColor(Color.RED);
         g2.drawRectangle(40, 40, getWidth() - 80, getHeight() - 80);
     }
}
```

The mechanism is as follows:

- A click is handled on the event dispatching thread of swing.
- Here it says to `repaint` the panel in 50 ms.
- A bit later `repaintComponent` is called from the swing framework in the conjunction of erasing the background and painting the child components.

In `paintComponent` the `Graphics` parameter for all newer java versions actually is a `Graphics2D` which has many nice methods.